# Can anyone explain this code line of MATLAB with unix command & what it does?

Tags: matlab, command

CODE: Is there a way to run this code on Windows inspite of it having a unix command?

```
     function [region_borders,mult,as_idx,color_asign,Iq_segmt] = segment(Iq,ext3_sigma,ext3_k,ext3_min,segPath)

     imwrite(Iq,'tempquery.ppm','ppm');

     %%THIS LINE
     unix([segPath ' ' num2str(ext3_sigma),' ',num2str(ext3_k),' ',num2str(ext3_min),' tempquery.ppm tempsegout.ppm']);

     Iq_segmt = imread('tempsegout.ppm');

     as_idx=0; .................
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Use [`system`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) instead.  `unix` executes Unix system commands.  `system` is the more general command that is operating system independent... so:

```
system([segPath ' ' num2str(ext3_sigma),' ',num2str(ext3_k),' ',num2str(ext3_min),' tempquery.ppm tempsegout.ppm']);
```

However, I can't really tell you what it does because `segPath`, `ext3_sigma`, `ext3_k` and `ext3_min` aren't explained in this context.  It would help if you provided the line of the code that is actually calling the `segment` function.